# How do I 'tail -f' to a file, while also executing a script utilising that file indefinitely?

Tags: shell-script, tail, rsyslog

I am so close to getting it, but fear I have spent too long looking at this and am getting lost as to how to accomplish what I want.

#### What I am trying to do:

Take the access log from my server, parse the output and feed it to the [matomo log importer](https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo-log-analytics), so it is importing logs "live". Essentially, `web server -> log -> parse -> matomo log importer`

#### What have I done:

I can parsing the output of my access.log with tail and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) as such:

```
tail -f /var/log/access.log | jq --compact-output '{ip: (.request.remote_addr | .[:-6]), host: .request.host, path: .request.uri, status: "\(.status)", referrer: "", user_agent: .request.headers."User-Agent"[], length: .size, generation_time_milli: .duration, date: (.ts | strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"))}'
```

This gives me a `JSON` format that the matomo log importer [understands](https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo-log-analytics#setup-nginx-logs). I then have a script that needs reads a log and imports it.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "${@}" | python3 ./import_logs3.py \
 --url=https://location --token-auth={TOKEN} \
 --enable-http-errors --enable-http-redirects --enable-static --enable-bots \
 --idsite=1 --recorders=4 --log-format-name=nginx_json {FILE}
```

Here is where I am stuck, as the script expects a file to process and finishes when it has parsed it. I'd like the script to run indefinitely, so the logs get imported "live". The examples use something such as [rsyslog](https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo-log-analytics#setup-rsyslog) which executes the script each time the log file gets updated.

How would I go about doing something similar? Utilise `tee`? If I `tee` to a file, how do I execute the script pointing to that file each time it gets updated?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `the script expects a file to process and finishes when it has parsed it` – What happens if the file is a named fifo? Hopefully the script won't exit until there is no writing process anymore. Even if you need separate processes to write sequentially (with possible intermissions when none of them keeps the fifo open for writing), it's easy to open the fifo from a shell to prevent the reading process from exiting. Do you need assistance in testing this?

Comment: Ah yes, a fifo file works perfectly for this! Problem is, I am having trouble getting the command I have to output to the fifo file (or any file for that matter). Then I have to think how to have this as a script so I can control it with systemd. `tail -f /var/log/access.log | jq --compact-output '{ip: (.request.remote_addr | .[:-6]), host: .request.host, path: .request.uri, status: "\(.status)", referrer: "", user_agent: .request.headers."User-Agent"[], length: .size, generation_time_milli: .duration, date: (.ts | strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"))}' | tee -a log.json` doesn't work at all.

Comment: Okay, looks like using tee to fifo and make sure it's unbuffered works. Problem now comes to the matomo script, I don't think it actually processes the logs until it has reached the end of the file, so `fifo` might not be the way.

Comment: If your webserver is Apache (and quite possibly if it's Nginx, too) you can write the access.log directly to a process. Would that be acceptable?